# What does "As such, .." mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I though `As such` means `So ..` or `Because of to that ..` or `Thus ..`.

But a translation site seems says differently, but not very clearly.

So, what does it mean?

Examples for common usage would be great !

Comment: I think [it's answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13481/meaning-and-usage-of-as-such) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As such,..." means "Being such a thing,..." It is often used, incorrectly, to mean "Therefore,..." Correct:

```
"Such" is a pronoun. As such, it requires an antecedent (in this case, "pronoun").
```

Incorrect:

```
He likes pizza. As such, he orders it frequently.
```

I was taught that a pronoun's antecedent should be in the same sentence, so I almost never start a sentence with "As such," but I do use it to begin a clause after a semicolon:

```
I'm a grammar freak; as such, I observe the rules as strictly as I can.
```